# Filter out multiple items from array in Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a multi select dropdown in Angular. I want to filter it out based on name.

```js
var users = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];
```

How will i filter out John and Tom both if i select them in my multi select dropdown. Assuming i am getting this from the multiselect dropdown.

```js
this.selectedItems = 
[
{"id":1,"name":"John"},                             
{"id":2,"name":"Tom"}
];
```

Comment: @RahulJain Please share the code you tried, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated and screenshots of the expected output for best resolution!

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this by using filter method.

```
let selectedUserArray = ["John","Tom"]; //selected user names from the dropdown.

let finalArr = [];

selectedUserArray.forEach((item)=>{
    var name = users.filter( el=>el.name == item );
    finalArr.push.apply(finalArr,name);
});

console.log(finalArr); // This is the final Array you want to approach
```

Comment: Thank you, this works if i have selected array as just names. Below one works if i have index with them also.

Answer (score 1):

```
const selectedUserNames = this.selectedItems.map(user => user.name);
const selectedUsers = users.filter(user => selectedUserNames.indexOf(user.name) > -1)
```

Comment: Thank you! this works in case if you get response as in array with index.